# Postfix changes to main.cf are not loaded

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, smtp, restrictions

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

```
root@vm1613:/etc/postfix# vim /etc/postfix/main.cf

[...]
# default restrictions
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
[...]

root@vm1613:/etc/postfix# postfix check
root@vm1613:/etc/postfix#

root@vm1613:/etc/courier# service postfix restart
 * Stopping Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix                                                                                                                                                                                                                        [ OK ]
 * Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix
```

when i check `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` the result is:

```
root@vm1613:/etc/courier# postconf -d smtpd_recipient_restrictions
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

Why?

Why main.cf is not "loaded" into Postfix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running "postconf -d", check the man page.  That prints the default settings instead of the actual settings.  Leave the "-d" out of your command and you should see what you're expecting.